# SolrCloud - Caching not working

Tags: caching, solr

We are using solrcloud 5.0 for indexing and querying data.

We found intermittently querying become slow. After analysing (through SolrCloud Admin Panel) we found that documentCache size become 0 when it slow. There were no evictions (confirmed through in SolrCloud Admin Panel). What could be reason for documentCache become emply?

We have following documentCache  Setting in solrconfig.xml.

```
<documentCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="40960" initialSize="40960"
  autowarmCount="0" cleanupThread="true"/>
```

What could be reason for documentCache become emply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLR clears the cache after each commit and you might be in pre-warming state and could be the reason for performance delay.

Comment: Is there any way by which we can ensure that newly added documents are visible without losing data in documentCache? We are trying to use softcommit but it also flushes all documents in documentCache.

Comment: Have you enabled softCommit...? Reduce the softCommit to 1 sec

Comment: Yes...we have enabled autosoftcommit in softconfig.xml but still new document is not visible (confirmed via solr admin console). <autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>50</maxTime>
    </autoSoftCommit>

Comment: Which version are you using..? in 5.2.1 I enable commit as below in solr.in.sh (Basically while starting solr) this will be used by executable solr.   SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime=1000"
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.autoCommit.maxTime=15000"

Comment: We are using solr cloud 5.2 version. 

We have also set -Dsolr.autoCommit.maxTime=1000. After executing below code it adds documents and visible for query. But it also flushes documentCache which is our main concern. 

solrconfig.xml
==============

<autoCommit>
      <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit>
      <maxTime>50</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>


Code
==

CloudSolrClient cloudClient = new CloudSolrClient(zkHost);
cloudClient.setDefaultCollection("forms");
UpdateResponse resp = cloudClient.add(doc);